# Laravel Intervention\Image Package gives error

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project where I'm trying to create image thumbnail when uploading an image using a Intervention/Image Package, but I seem to be getting following errors:

Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException

Image source not readable

I am using Laravel 8.

**ProductController.php**

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Models\Product;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Auth;
    use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
    

    class ProductController extends Controller
    {
    
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
            request()->validate([              
                'product_name' => ['required', 'min:2', 'max:50'],
                'product_price' => 'required',
                'product_desc' => ['required', 'min:2', 'max:400'],
                'product_img' => 'image|nullable|max:1999
            ]);
    
            // Handle File Upload
            if($request->hasFile('product_img')){
                // Get filename with the extension
                $filenameWithExt = $request->file('product_img')->getClientOriginalName();
                // Get just filename
                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // Get just ext
                $extension = $request->file('product_img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                // Filename to store
                $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                // Upload Image
                $path = $request->file('product_img')->storeAs('public/uploads', $fileNameToStore);
            }
    
    
            $product = new Product();
            $product->product_name = request('product_name');
            $product->product_price = request('product_price');
            $product->product_desc = request('product_desc');
            $user_id = Auth::id();
            $product->user_id = $user_id;
    
            if($request->hasFile('product_img')){
                $product->product_img = $fileNameToStore;
            }
            $product->save();
    
    
            // create a thumbnail of the image using intervention image library
            $manager = new ImageManager();
            $image = $manager->make('storage/uploads' . $fileNameToStore)->resize(300, 200);
            $image->save('storage/photos_thumb' . $fileNameToStore);
    
            return redirect('/products');
        }

    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.mainlayout')
@section('content')
    <div class="product-wrapper">

        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="/products/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="product-name">Products name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product-name" name="product_name" placeholder="" value="" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="product-desc">Product price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product-price" name="product_price" placeholder="" value="" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="file" name="product_img">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="product-desc">Product description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="product-desc-textarea" name="product_desc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Do you complete full procedure? Like composer command, add in service provider. etc.. http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel

Comment: yes i wrote composer require intervention/image into command line, then added Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class into '$providers array' , 'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class into 'aliases array' and then php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravelRecent"

Comment: In header section just use this `use Image;`